# Laravel 7 cognito used in web and apps

Tags: laravel, amazon-cognito, laravel-7

I want to build laravel 7 with aws cognito and use this package [aws-sdk-php-laravel](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel).

This project will be made for the web & apps.

so how the laravel handle login from apps then apps get API from web with same token from cognito?

This is my first time use cognito, usually use auth-jwt.

Answer (score 1):

After many tries without package

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CognitoController extends Controller
{

    private $key;
    private $secret;
    private $region;
    private $version;
    private $client_id;
    private $client_secret;
    private $user_pool_id;

    private $aws;
    private $client;

    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->key = 'xxxxxx';
        $this->secret = 'xxxxxx';
        $this->region = 'xxxxxx';
        $this->version = 'latest';
        $this->client_id = 'xxxxxx';
        $this->client_secret = 'xxxxxx';
        $this->user_pool_id = 'xxxxxx';

        $config = [
            'credentials' => [
                'key' => $this->key,
                'secret' => $this->secret,
            ],
            'region' => $this->region,
            'version' => $this->version,
            'app_client_id' => $this->client_id,
            'app_client_secret' => $this->client_secret,
            'user_pool_id' => $this->user_pool_id,
        ];

        $this->aws = new \Aws\Sdk($config);

        $this->client = $this->aws->createCognitoIdentityProvider();

    }

    public function login()
    {
        $username = 'guest';
        $password = 'password';

        $result = $this->client->adminInitiateAuth([
                                    'AuthFlow' => 'ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',
                                    'AuthParameters' => [
                                        'USERNAME' => $username,
                                        'PASSWORD' => $password,
                                        'SECRET_HASH' => $this->secretHash($username),
                                    ],
                                    'ClientId' => $this->client_id,
                                    'UserPoolId' => $this->user_pool_id,
                                ]);

        $access_token = $result->get('AuthenticationResult')['AccessToken'];

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r( $result );
        echo '<br/>';
        print_r( $access_token );
        echo '</pre>';
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $username = 'guest';
        $password = 'password';
        $email = 'guest@email.com';
        $phone_number = '+819000000000';

        $result = $this->client->signUp([
                                    'ClientId' => $this->client_id,
                                    'Password' => $password,
                                    'SecretHash' => $this->secretHash($username),
                                    'UserAttributes' => [
                                        [
                                            'Name' => 'phone_number',
                                            'Value' => $phone_number,
                                        ],
                                        [
                                            'Name' => 'email',
                                            'Value' => $email,
                                        ]
                                    ],
                                    'Username' => $username
                                ]);

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r( $result );
        echo '</pre>';

    }

    public function register_confirm()
    {
        $username = 'guest';
        $confirmationCode = '123456'; // from email verification code

        $result = $this->client->confirmSignUp([
                                    'ClientId' => $this->client_id,
                                    'Username' =>  $username,
                                    'SecretHash' => $this->secretHash($username),
                                    'ConfirmationCode' => $confirmationCode,
                                ]);

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r( $result );
        echo '</pre>';
    }

    public function list()
    {
        $search = ['UserPoolId' => $this->user_pool_id];

        $users = $this->client->listUsers($search)->toArray();

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r( $users );
        echo '</pre>';
    }

    private function secretHash($username) {
        $clientId = $this->client_id;
        $clientSecret = $this->client_secret;
        $s = hash_hmac('sha256', $username . $clientId, $clientSecret, true);
        return base64_encode($s);
    }

}
```

token from auth cognito is it the same as the token when use [JWTAuth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth)?

Laravel Socialite doesn't have a cognito platform yet

Answer (score 0):

You can configure AWS Cognito for OAuth and use one of the Laravel Oauth plugin to connect and authenticate with Cognito. I hope you will be storing user credentials in AWS Cognito User Pool.

Complete documentation (High Level) of AWS Cognito - https://www.slideshare.net/awsugkochi/acdkochi19-enterprise-grade-security-for-web-and-mobile-applications-on-aws

Documentation of AWS Cognito architecture for OAuth configuration - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-user-pool-oauth-2-0-grants/

Documentation of Laravel Socialite to connect with AWS Cognito over OAuth and get authentication.